# Android certificate is expired

Tags: android, certificate, keystore, google-play

I currently have an error message when signing my app, saying that the certificate is expired (not the debug one). (I know that is surprising since Android certificate should be available many years !).
I can't create a new certificate because I get an error when updating my apk on the PlayStore (certificate of the apk have to be the same as the previous one)

Is it even possible to renew my keystore ?

Is the only possiblity create a new application ?

Comment: On this page: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html it tells you to make sure your certificate is good for at least 25 years. It appears you missed that, and you'll have to start over fresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe (but I never tested) you can regenerate a certificate with the same couple public/private keys. If it does not work, unfortunately I think you will have to generate a new certificate. Do not forget to add the `-validity <valdays>` option with a very large number of days. You will also have to change the package name as explained [in this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html).

**UPDATE**

According to @KIDdAe comment (see below), Google verifies the SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate and not only the certificate signature with the public key. Therefore recreating a new certificate with the same key is useless since the SHA1 of that new certificate will differ from the initial one.

Comment: It won't work. The new (extended) certificate will have a different public key.

Comment: Yes, if you are using the command line from the android doc. I don't know if it can be done with keytool but it is possible to create a new self-signed certificate with the same key (with OpenSSL for instance)

Comment: Google tests `SHA1` fingerprints of the certificate to see if the app is signed with the correct one. Even if I'm able to generate it with the old keys, will the `SHA1` change ?

Comment: If you're signing with the old keys, you still won't be able to publish, because the keys are expired.

Comment: @KIDdAe Ok, the full certificate is checked and not only the public key and the signature. Therefore a new certificate with new keys has to be generated. Thank you for this inforamtion, I updated my answer.